How do I write a VBA Conditional Formatting Code which paints the cell value if the value is not between the value of 2 different cells?
I'm struggling with writing the code which would create a conditional formatting rule in the E3 cell. I want the rule to paint the numberin the E3 cell if the value is not between the value of cells C5 and D5 and to leave it in black color if the value is in between the values of cells. Regular conditional formatting can not be used because the function of this macro includes copying and pasting the content from 1 sheet to another which unfortunatelly deletes the conditional formatting rules. The value in cells C5 and D5 often changes so I can't just put specific values in the code.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Below I have pasted my attempt which does not work. It does create a rule but it is not complete.
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim condition1 As FormatCondition, condition2 As FormatCondition
  


  Set rng = Range("E3")

   rng.FormatConditions.Delete


   Set condition1 = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
   Formula1:=Range("C5"), Formula2:=Range("D5"))
   
  
   With condition1
    .Font.Color = vbRed
   End With


What about it is not complete?

I've just tried your code and it worked fine

Also, are you intending to set the Condition to use the values-at-runtime, or would you be better with Formula1:="=$C$5", Formula2:="=$D$5"?

@Chronocidal the conditional formatting rule. When I manually click the cell on which the formatting rule gets created, everything is defined except the C5 and D5 cells.

@Nathan_Sav that's odd. I can't get mine to work

Well it does work, just the other way around that I would like.  Can I just add an if sentence and switch the colors?

What's your expected output?

Operator should be xlNotBetween.

Your comment about not being able to use Conditional Formatting because of a Copy/Paste gives a simpler solution all around.  Instead of using Copy/Paste, simply set the Value of your destination Range/Cell to the Value of the source Range/Cell.  Now you don't lose your formatting and your code runs faster.

@MGonet that works perfectly, thanks! But when I add more parts of the code (the part copies a table from one sheet to another) it kinda breaks. It changes the conditional formatting formula from "Format only call that contain value between..." to "Use a formula to choose which cells to format" when I open the manage rules function. I have also found out that even without the copy paste part of the code, it only works once or twice, then it just always paints the value red. I'm confused.

So I found out what was causing both the main and the smaller problem. Using xlNotBetween (thx @MGonet) worked perfectly.
But upon running the same code again the rng.FormatConditions.Delete didn't delete the formatting rule, it just removed the formatting result further causing the code not to work. Even if I manually deleted the code and ran it again it didn't work because it caused a similar problem I think.
The full code is posted below. Thanks everyone for help!
Sub bla()

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim condition1 As FormatCondition
  
  Set rng = Range("E3")

   Set condition1 = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotBetween, _
   Formula1:=Range("C3"), Formula2:=Range("D3"))
   
   With condition1
    .Font.Color = vbRed
   End With
   
End Sub


If you execute this code multiple times, you must give at the beginning
rng.FormatConditions.Delete
Otherwise, you'll have plenty of copies of that formatting.
However, I was unable to reproduce those problems with copying to another sheet. You would have to show what exact code you used.
